# Double integral units

Tags: calculus, integration

I was just doing some problems and was wondering whether the answer to the following question will have any units: I was thinking it should be units^3 since it represents volume above R below xy^2.
http://postimg.org/image/kfhegn4xj/

http://postimg.org/image/kfhegn4xj/
http://postimg.org/image/kfhegn4xj/

Comment: But then again, i dont think we state units in single definite integrals

Comment: I do't know what the $dR$ is supposed to be. The $xy^2$ could be many things, such as the density at $(x,y)$ of a lamina. In tha case the units would be mass. There are endlessly many other physical interpretations, under which the units would vary. Or the integral could calculate a unitless quantity.

Comment: dR is equivalent to dydx, assuming the region R is in the x-y plane

Comment: I just wanted to know if I have to write units^3 after my answer

Comment: Or would it be correct for me to write the answer as 1/24

Comment: Just write the number. I have not checked whether it is indeed $1/24$. (Now I have, it is.)